# Pintar un marco en c#

Tags: c#, estructuras

estoy en clase y nuestro profe nos está haciendo crear un marco de base para lo que sería un juego de snake, justo voy por la función que debe pintar el marco, pero tengo un cierto problema, y es que el lateral derecho, se me pinta justo al lado del izquierdo, en vez de pintarse como un marco... A ver si alguien me puede ayudar, esto es lo que tengo:

```
    static void pintaMarc()
            {
                //caracteres marc 186 ║, 187 ╗, 188 ╝, 200 ╚, 201 ╔, 205 ═

                int alçada = Console.WindowHeight - 10, amplada = Console.WindowWidth - 30;

                Console.Write('╔');
                for (int i = 0; i < amplada; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write('═');
                }
                Console.Write('╗');

                for (int x = 0; x < alçada; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write('\n');

                    for (int y = 0; y < amplada; y++)
                    {

                        if (y == 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write('║');
                        }

                        if (y == amplada - 1)
                        {
                            Console.Write('║');
                        }
                    }

                }
                Console.Write('\n');
                Console.Write('╚');
                for (int x = 0; x < amplada; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write('═');
                }
                Console.WriteLine('╝');
}
```

muchas gracias de antemano!

Adjunto captura de cómo se ejecuta:
[image: Como veis, se debería pintar en el espacio faltante, no justo al lado del otro margen]

Bien, pues al final lo hice con la función console.setcursorposition:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("╔");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 30);
            Console.WriteLine("╚");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(100, 1);
            Console.WriteLine("╗");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(100, 30);
            Console.WriteLine("╝");


            for (int y = 2; y < 100; y++)
            {
                int x = 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }

            for (int x = 2; x < 30; x++)
            {
                int y = 1;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("║");

                y = 100;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("║");
            }

            for (int y = 2; y < 100; y++)
            {
                int x = 30;
                Console.SetCursorPosition(y, x);
                Console.WriteLine("═");
            }
```

De forma que en el segundo for, las barras verticales, se van colocando paralelamente, a la distancia que asignes.

Comment: Creo que necesitas rellenar todo con espacios en blanco.... :-$  no se me ocurre otra solución... al momento de pintar la serpiente... solo reemplazar el espacio en blanco por el símbolo de la serpiente

Comment: Tal cual como dice @CristinaCarrascoAngulo, debes imprimir caracteres en blanco `Console.Write(' ');` antes de imprimir tu lateral derecho, si me explico?

Comment: Creo que es mejor imprimir en el buffer de la consola. Luego, cuando tenga que dibujar la serpiente va a tener toda una travesía si usa espacios.

Comment: Como el ejemplo que pusiste.... no sabia que se podía hacer eso, esta genial :-)

Comment: @CristinaCarrascoAngulo Ahora puse una implementación :P( y tambien se puede cambiar el color con Console.ForegroundColor, mira aqui :P[documentacion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.foregroundcolor(v=vs.110).aspx) )

Comment: Muchísimas gracias a todas las respuestas , ahora voy a postear la solución y a cerrar el tema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí esta la respuesta, revisalo :-)

```
 static void pintaMarc()
    {
        //caracteres marc 186 ║, 187 ╗, 188 ╝, 200 ╚, 201 ╔, 205 ═

        int alçada = Console.WindowHeight - 10, amplada = Console.WindowWidth - 30;

        Console.Write('╔');
        for (int i = 0; i < amplada; i++)
        {
            Console.Write('═');
        }
        Console.Write('╗');

        for (int x = 0; x < alçada; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('\n');

            for (int y = 0; y < amplada; y++)
            {

                if (y == 0)
                {
                    Console.Write('║');
                }

                if (y == amplada - 1)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ║");//Puse un espacio antes aqui
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(' ');//Esta linea agrega los espacios, en el else
                }
            }

        }
        Console.Write('\n');
        Console.Write('╚');
        for (int x = 0; x < amplada; x++)
        {
            Console.Write('═');
        }
        Console.WriteLine('╝');
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente como menciono @Arie:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        pintaMarc2();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void pintaMarc2()
    {
        //caracteres marc 186 ║, 187 ╗, 188 ╝, 200 ╚, 201 ╔, 205 ═
        int height = Console.WindowHeight - 10, width = Console.WindowWidth - 30;
        WriteAt("╔", 0, 0);
        WriteAt("╚", 0, height);
        WriteAt("╗", width, 0);
        WriteAt("╝", width, height);
        for (int i = 1; i < width; i++)
        {
            WriteAt("═", i, 0);
            WriteAt("═", i, height);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)
        {
            WriteAt("║", 0, i);
            WriteAt("║", width, i);
        }

    }

    protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write(s);
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Si funciona muy bien.

NOTA: La respuesta correcta debe ser de el :-)

Answer (score 1):

Buenas. Quizá debas usar una función como la que sigue:

```
protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y){
    try {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(s);
    } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e){
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Para imprimir la caja la implementación es algo como esto:

```
using System;

class Sample {
    protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y){
        /* metodo de arriba ^_^ */
    }

    protected static void printBox(int sizeX, int sizeY){
        int limiteX = sizeX - 1, limiteY = sizeY - 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < limiteY; i++){
            WriteAt("║", 0, i);
            WriteAt("║", limiteX, i);
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < limiteX; i++){
            WriteAt("═", i, 0);
            WriteAt("═", i, limiteY);
        }

        WriteAt ("╔", 0, 0);
        WriteAt ("╗", limiteX, 0);
        WriteAt ("╚", 0, limiteY);
        WriteAt ("╝", limiteX, limiteY);
    }

    public static void Main(){
        Console.Clear();
        printBox(7, 8);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el ejemplo en el [Sitio de microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx)